What does "it" in "it was awkward" refer to?
In Anna Karenina (2012), Vronsky arrives at Anna's house just as her husband Aleksei is leaving, their eyes briefly meeting.
Vronsky mentions a note from Anna that indicated her husband would be out. In response, Anna
states that Aleksei was late and that it serves him right:

Anna: And you... Why do you call him my husband?
He isn't my husband, he's a clock.
Vronsky: But it was awkward. My honour. You made an agreement.

Then Anna shifts the conversation to the movements of her baby in her pregnant belly.
What does "it" in "it was awkward" refer to?

The situation, of course - the lover and husband accidentally meeting.

It's not anaphoric, (or at least not clearly so) in that it does not refer to a contextually salient entity and it can't be replaced by other 3rd person personal pronouns. It has the purely syntactic function of filling the obligatory subject position.
